# Swift: NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil on devices

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I found something that could solve my problem in Obj-c, but I'm not able to translate the code, so I'm asking for a Swift solution.

I'm parsing some data from a JSON file and I get an issue retrieving the date; here is the code :

```
println(data) // "Fri, 16 Jan 2015 11:49:00 +0100"

var dateFormatter           = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat    = "EEE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
let formattedDate           = dateFormatter.dateFromString(data)

println(formattedDate) // returns 'Optional(2015-01-16 11:49:00 +0100)' if running on an iOs Simulator
                       // returns 'nil' if runnig on an iPhone
```

Like I write in the code comments, I get correctly the optional type of the date if I run it on an iOs Simulator or in the playground, but I get nil if it is running on an iPhone.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a timeZone/locale to your `dateFormatter` maybe?

Comment: adding    dateFormatter.timeZone      = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") doesn't change the result..

Comment: @Stizz: Check with `dateFormatter.dateFormat    = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: @MidhunMP: nothing had changed with your advice :/

Comment: Try `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`, and see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7

Comment: @rintaro: Thaks! it works well now!

Answer (score 7):

*For the others who get here and don't read the comments of the initial post* ;)

As @rintaro pointed out - and what was my problem too - you have to **add a locale** when you use fixed-format dates:

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7

So in **Swift 3** you would have to add

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```