# Swift 2.1 xcode 7 fatal error: when i change string to date but is working in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate

I am simply string convert in nsdate but its always return me error **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**  Line number 6 **let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!**

Here is my code. Please suggest a solution, because this code working in swift 2.0 version but is't crash on swift 2.1

```
func doSomething(getdate:String)  -> String   {
    let start = getdate
    print("start==\(start)")
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-­MM-­dd HH:mm:ss"
    let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
    let date:String? = (self.timeAgoSinceDate(startDate, numericDates: Bool()))
    return date!
}
```

when I print a start variable is look like this **start==2015-09-15 06:35:53**

Comment: I'd wildly guess that this is some 12/24 hour setting issue, so set the locale of the formatter to en_US_POSIX e.g. `DateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`.

Comment: i have use this but its not working and i am sure this is 24 hours time , I have set static date in start variable But its not working  **let start ="2015-09-15 06:35:53"** may be this is xcode issue now i am using xcode 7.0

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for your error is the forced unwrapping of a `nil` return from method `.dateFromString()` method (class method for `NSDateFormatter`). You code is, in it's current form, unsafe, and just happened to pass without runtime errors in your previous runs.

From the language reference for class `NSDateFormatter` method `.dateFromString()`, we have

> ...
>
> Returns a date representation of a given string interpreted using the
>   receiver’s current settings. A date representation of string
>   interpreted using the receiver’s current settings. **If dateFromString:
>   can not parse the string, returns nil**.

To begin with, we should make sure the behaviour of your code is well-defined by avoiding forced unwrapping of optional, by using `if-let` clauses (or `guard-let`, or nil coalescing operator `??`) instead of forced unwrapping (`!`).

Now, I don't have the context of your code, but consider fixing the forced unwrapping in you function to change it into a form like

```
func doSomething(getdate:String)  -> String   {
    let start = getdate
    print("start==\(start)")
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-­MM-­dd HH:mm:ss"
    var date : String?
    if let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start) {
        date = (self.timeAgoSinceDate(startDate, numericDates: Bool()))
    }

    return date ?? ""
}
```

---

With this out of the way, we can proceed to examine why `.dateFromString(start)` fails to parse the string.

Based on the following threads

- [NSDateFormatter returns nil in swift and iOS SDK 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153381/nsdateformatter-returns-nil-in-swift-and-ios-sdk-8-0),
- [Swift: NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil on devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496001/swift-nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-nil-on-devices),

possibly, you need to specify the `.locale` property of the `dateFormatter`. Try to add one of the two following line

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us")
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

right after you've defined the `dateFormatter.dateFormat`.

---

Note, however, that the most probable cause as to why `.dateFromString(start)` fails to parse the string, and hence returns `nil`, is that your string `start` simply does not comply to `dateFormat`. It does look, given your printed output of `start`, that it does, but please have an extra look to see if this is really always the case, for all possible calls to your function. Neither `.locale` or `.timeZone` should affect whether `.dateFromString(...)` can parse its argument or not. Only `.dateFormat` controls this success or non-success of string parsing.

Comment: drfi setting .locale will not change the timeZone, so the resulting date can still be different from wanted result

Comment: You are right! With your `.timeZone` fix, I get the correct date for my own timezone (got -2 hrs before). However, I don't know if any of our solutions explains why the `.dateFromString(...)` returns nil? Even without a timeZone specified, a date should be returned, right?

Comment: drfi it s really hard to say, it could be a simple typing mistake or something else. Optional binding can help him to see, what is wrong ... and it is the only safe and 'best practices'  way, how to write 'solid' code

Comment: @user3441734 Yes, I agree, and I also suspect that the string `start` does not really conform to the `.dateFormat`, even if it looks like it does (given his printed example).

Comment: dfri .locale can effect the result. it is not the case for the dateFormat as in your example, but if you specify it as "yyyy-MMM-dd" MMM part will be .locale sensitive. Just take this in account :-)

Comment: This code is not working please help me , its always go to else condition

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let str = "2015-09-15 06:35:53"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
guard let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str) else {
    exit(-1)
}
print(startDate)        // 2015-09-15 04:35:53 +0000
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
guard let startDateUTC = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str) else {
    exit(-1)
}
print(startDateUTC)     // 2015-09-15 06:35:53 +0000
```

Please, follow dfri instructions about binding the result of dateFromString()

If there in no specification about timezone in your string, use "UTC" as timeZone. Then you have some 'reference' date in very known format and you can compare it or make something else ... If you know the timeZone of the source of your string, you can use that timeZone directly.

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

will NOT change the timeZone settings, so check the resulting NSDate before use!

For your reference I recommend you [this reading](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/)

Comment: Hello sir , this is not working , its always go to exit(-1) , please help me

Comment: copy and pate all this code to your playground and check it again. if it 'always go to exit", that means that your date string is not in the format, you did publish here. at first play with this code in your playground, try to change str, .dateFormat and check the documentation. properly check your 'date' string and corespondent .dateFormat. if you receive nil from .dateFromString, the trouble must be there